# visual foxpro password field decode php

Tags: php, passwords, decode, decoding, foxpro

I'm having trouble comparing two variables for logging to a system i'm working at.
We have a visual fox pro system in the company and I am adding a PHP module to it, so I have to use existing .DBF files for consulting some data.
When it comes to consulting users this happens...

[image: how I see the password field]

- the left part indicates how i see column "USU_CCLAVE" containing the passwords in a DBF viewer
- the right part shows how it looks when a paste the column to notepad++
- And bottom left shows the code for checking user & pass that doesn't work

I am not able to check user password combination from my program since password field its enconded. I don't want to build a parallel user database, instead, i want to use the data alredy there. Any way for decoding thist column ?. I'm not having problem accessing the table from php, that works fine, I just want to decode this column in php so i can check if user its correct

(If I echo the column values in a browser i get blank, except in some cases that show /316, or some garbage as in the image )

i'm sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how the VFP system encodes it. You need to find that out. Then re-implement that in PHP. Then, on the PHP side, you take an entered password and encode it and see if that matches what is in the database. If the garbage matches, the user entered a correct password.

If you don't know how the VFP system encrypts then you are wasting your time.

This all assumes that the original VFP developer did it properly and used an non-reversible encryption method.

Comment: Thanks, nice explation btw. I had hope i didn't have to contact the VFP developer, but I won't waste more time since this is the only thing left to finish my job

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the code in the VFP system that encrypts the password and then implement the same encryption in Php.